# Data not getting posted into mysql database using volley?

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-volley

> I am using the google's Volley library to send data to mysql database.I am not getting a Error but my onResponse method returns RESPONSE: {"msg":false,"status":false} Can anyone tell me what it means and how I can fix it.

```
  private void insertToDb() {
    billType = (invEstSwitch.isChecked() ? textViewEstimate : textViewInvoice)
            .getText().toString();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("custInfo", custSelected.toString());
        jsonObject.put("invoiceNo", textViewInvNo.getText().toString());
        jsonObject.put("barcode", barCode.getText().toString());
        jsonObject.put("desc", itemDesc.getText().toString());
        jsonObject.put("weight", weightLine.getText().toString());
        jsonObject.put("rate", rateAmount.getText().toString());
        jsonObject.put("makingAmt", makingAmount.getText().toString());
        jsonObject.put("net_rate", netRate.getText().toString());
        jsonObject.put("itemTotal", itemtotal.getText().toString());
        jsonObject.put("vat", textViewVat.getText().toString());
        jsonObject.put("sum_total", textViewSum.getText().toString());
        jsonObject.put("bill_type", billType);
        jsonObject.put("date", textViewCurrentDate.getText().toString());


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        itemSelectedJson.put(index, jsonObject);
        index++;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonobj.put("itemarray",itemSelectedJson);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, INVEST_URL, jsonobj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("RESPONSE", response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("JSONERROR",error.toString());
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }
    };


    final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.add(objectRequest);

}

//And I am calling this method from onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) like
 case R.id.action_save:
            insertToDb();
            return true;
```

> What I am trying to do is 
>   1)send a json Array to my php script.
>   2)parse the json Array and 
>   3)insert the data into mysql table.

This is my php script

```
 <?php
          require "init.php";
          $json = file_get_contents('php://input'); 

          $data = json_decode($json);
          // Now process the array of objects
           foreach ( $data as $inv ) {
           $custInfo = $inv->custInfo;
           $rate =     $inv->rate;
           $weight=    $inv->weight;
           $desc=      $inv->desc;
           $makingAmt= $inv->makingAmt;
           $vat=       $inv->vat;
           $itemTotal= $inv->itemTotal;
           $sum_total= $inv->sum_total;
           $barcode=   $inv->barcode;
           $net_rate=  $inv->net_rate;
           $date=      $inv->date;
           $invoiceNo= $inv->invoiceNo;
           $bill_type= $inv->bill_type;
            $sql = "INSERT INTO selected_items 
                 (custInfo, invoiceNo, barcode, desc, 
                  weight, rate, makingAmt,net_rate,
                  itemTotal,vat,sum_total,bill_type,date) 
                VALUES
                 ('$custInfo','$invoiceNo','$barcode','$desc',
                  '$weight','$rate','$makingAmt','$net_rate',
                  '$itemTotal','$vat','$sum_total','$bill_type','$date')";
        $res = mysqli_query($sql,$con);
        echo $res;
        if(!$res){
            $result = new stdClass();
            $result->status = false;
            $result->msg = mysql_error();
            echo json_encode($result);
            exit;
        }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju I am not getting any error it just says RESPONSE: {"msg":false,"status":false}; in the logcat.

Comment: `$result->status = false;
            $result->msg = mysql_error();`, you are only adding false in code and there is no error, so `msg` is also false.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju thank you for pointing that out.Can you tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: on what basis you want to set `status`??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju I am new to programming I just want to display a Toast if data is getting inserted into the database.Can you tell me why my json data is not getting inserted into the database.

Answer (score 2):

according to your code,

```
$result->status = false;// you are only assigning false here
$result->msg = mysql_error();
```

There is no error, so `msg` is also false.

Comment: can you tell me how can i check if a json array or json object is reaching the php code

Comment: on what basis , `msg` should contain value??

Comment: On successful insert it should say "Data inserted Successfully" thats it

Comment: what is `echo $res;` giving??

Comment: PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/webapp/demoinvest.php on line 10 this is the error that i get.Actually my code for php is on google cloud vm.So when I just run my php code i get this error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96659/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-androidnewbee).